# Full folder /wal

Tags: postgresql, backup

How can I efficiently delete thousands of WAL (Write-Ahead Logging) files in the /wal directory in a PostgreSQL database to free up disk space while ensuring the integrity of the database?

> -rw------- 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Feb  5 14:11 000000020000000B0000004D

> -rw------- 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Feb  6 03:13 000000020000000B0000004E

> -rw------- 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Feb  6 07:57 000000020000000B0000004F

I have a broken backup because the stanza keeps showing me this error.

> ERROR: [082]: WAL segment 000000020000000B00000093 was not archived
> before the 60000ms timeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the archiver has a problem. Set `archive_mode = off` and restart PostgreSQL, then it will delete the WAL segments automatically after the next checkpoint. You can trigger a checkpoint with the `CHECKPOINT` command if you don't want to wait.

Never, ever, delete any files in `pg_wal` yourself.

Comment: So you're saying that if I set archive_mode=off and restart PostgreSQL, all WAL files will be automatically deleted?

Comment: After then next checkpoint yes. Except the WAL segments that cannot yet be deleted.

Comment: Thx! It works!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your archiving setup is broken.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/wal-configuration.html

> Also, if WAL archiving is used, old segments cannot be removed or recycled until they are archived. If WAL archiving cannot keep up with the pace that WAL is generated, or if archive_command or archive_library fails repeatedly, old WAL files will accumulate in pg_wal until the situation is resolved.

So - you either need to fix your wal archiving or turn it off (remove the `archive_command`). Obviously you will then want to get your backups working again as soon as possible.